# Select where array?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Tengo el siguiente array guardado en una DB, dentro del perfil de usuario, los siguiente locales: "Abasto, Flores, Caballito"

Necesito filtrarle al usuario solo información de esos locales y estoy intentando lo siguiente, pero no logro dar con la consulta.

```html
<?php
               
              conectar();

              $permisoa = "SELECT permisoa FROM users WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";
              $rspermiso = mysqli_query ($link, $permisoa);

             while ($imprimo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rspermiso)){
              $permi=$imprimo['permisoa'];

              echo $permi;
//muestro ok la consulta con los locales que quiero traer a modo de test.


}

    $sql="SELECT * FROM historial where estado = 'PENDIENTE' AND locales IN ($permi)";
    $rs = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);
      
      while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
```

Que puede estar sucediendo? o que estoy utilizando mal? Si en lugar de poner ($permi) pongo (Abasto) me lista todo abasto, pero ya cuando pongo (Abasto, Caballito) no me lista nada.

Comment: La columna `permisoa` ¿ contiene un solo permiso a la vez ó contiene permisos separados por comas?

Comment: Almagro seria un local es decir si la consulta fuera   $sql="SELECT * FROM historial WHERE estado = 'PENDIENTE' AND locales= 'Almagro'"; me devolveria todo lo pendiente del local almagro, pero el problema va cuando al mismo usuario quiero listarle, almagro, caballito, etc y si pongo   $sql="SELECT * FROM historial WHERE estado = 'PENDIENTE' AND locales= 'Almagro, Caballito, etc'"; no muestra nada, supongo porque buscara coincidencia total en Almagro, Caballito, etc y no que cada palabra esta separada por comas ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema puede ser que el contenido de $permi viene sin comillas, al ser strings, cada una de las opciones dentro del IN debería ir entre comillas:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM historial where estado = 'PENDIENTE' AND locales IN ('Abasto', 'Caballito')";
```

Deberías por lo tanto dividir $permi con un explode (no un implode, ese es para juntar los datos de un array en un string). Agregarle comillas a los datos y volver a juntar los datos con un implode:

```
$permiExploded = explode(",",$permi);
$newPermi = array();
foreach ($permiExploded as $per){
    array_push($newPermi,"'".trim($per)."'");
}
$permi = implode(",",$newPermi);
$sql="SELECT * FROM historial where estado = 'PENDIENTE' AND locales IN ($permi)";
```

Ahora al incluir $permi dentro de la query ésta debería llevar las comillas correctamente.

Comment: Me convence tu logica, pero ahora recibo un fatal error : :  Only variables can be passed by reference in --  array_push("'".trim($per)."'");

Comment: Mi error, me faltó definir el array en el array_push, ahora está editado, prueba nuevamente y me comentas

Answer (score 0):

debes descomponer el arreglo separado por comas puedes usar la funcion implode(",", $permi)

ya que la funcion IN  de sql debe incluir los elementos separado por comas

ejemplo:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM historial where estado = 'PENDIENTE' AND locales IN (".$permi.")";
        $rs = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);

          while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
```

Comment: Mmm esto lo he probado pero me arroja lo siguiente: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in, creo que mi problema es que lo que yo almaceno es un string en la db, ya que le hago un var_dump y me muestra string(43) "Abasto, Flores, Caballito"

Comment: entonces solo deberas pasar IN (".$permi.")" ya que lo tienes como una cadena. $sql="SELECT * FROM historial where estado = 'PENDIENTE' AND locales IN (".$permi.")";

Comment: juan carlos, ahi publique una respuesta con el error que me deja

Answer (score 0):

```html
  conectar();

              $permisoa = "SELECT permisoa FROM users WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";
              $rspermiso = mysqli_query ($link, $permisoa);

             while ($imprimo = mysqli_fetch_array($rspermiso)){
              
              $permi=$imprimo['permisoa'];
              echo $permi;
              var_dump($permi);
}

    $sql="SELECT * FROM historial where estado = 'PENDIENTE' AND locales IN (".$permi.")";
    $rs = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);
      
      while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
```

Al poner IN (".$permi.")"; me arroja

```html
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

Answer (score 0):

He intentado directamente desde phpmyadmin realizar la consulta y me devuelve 0 columnas, la consulta que utilizo es la siguiente.

```
SELECT * FROM historial WHERE locales IN ("Abasto, Caballito, Almagro")
```

Pero si saco 2 locales y dejo solamente uno, funciona. En cadena no.

```
SELECT * FROM historial WHERE locales IN ("Almagro")
```

Asi funciona, pero no me sirve